# List overwriting data on all positions before

Tags: c#

ToolMy Problem when i would like add a new item to a list this item overwrite all other items befor.

```
public static List<Tool_OP> list = new List<Tool_OP>();
BinaryReader fs = new BinaryReader(File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open));
do
{
    Tool_OP item = new Tool_OP();
    if (!item.ReadRecord(fs)) break;
    list.Add(item);
} while (true);
fs.Close();
```

Here is a part of my record class. My Record is OK when i debbug. I dont know why my list on every add overite all items with my actually item. I have a ReadString Method to get strings from my Binary File.

```
class Tool_OP
{
  public static string      comment;
  public static long        op_idn;

  public static string ReadString(int max, BinaryReader fs)
  {
      byte[] Buf = new byte[max];
      string NewStr = "";
      Buf = fs.ReadBytes(max);

      for (int ii = 0; ii < max; ii++)
      {
          if (Buf[ii] == 0) return NewStr;
          NewStr = NewStr + Convert.ToChar(Buf[ii]);
      }
      return NewStr;
  }

  public Boolean ReadRecord(BinaryReader fs)
  {
      comment = ReadString(120, fs);
      op_idn = fs.ReadInt32();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're misdiagnosing the problem (or I am misunderstanding the question), but there's no information to determine this.

Comment: Are you saying you want to clear the list when you read the data in?  or are you saying all the items in the list have the same data, from the last record?

Comment: I will say all items have the same data from the last record

Comment: Have you debugged it to make sure that it is atleast reading and populating item itself in ReadRecord? Can we see ReadRecord? Have you set it to pass in fs by reference?

Comment: Yes the record is OK but when i add the item it overwrite all items before

Comment: But we can't see this code. Please show us the code that is iterating the list to validate the data. The bug could be with that. This is why we need to see all your code (within reason) to assist. We only have a little bit of it.

Comment: Your methods do not use **ref** in the function definitions. So it is just passing a copy of fs in each time. It will never move pass the same place. See https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiE0KCzl7zMAhUIahoKHdITAKgQFgg9MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fcsharp%2Fcsharp_reference_parameters.htm&usg=AFQjCNF8zxLm2g_5wCdl_KtfTom83ZyTtQ.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, the existence of the `static` keyword for the fields explains everything.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch only the list variable is set as static. But it is all code within a method. We don't see all the code. It isn't a static method but a static variable. I still feel that using the ref keyword is needed.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, look carefully at the `Tool_OP` fields.  Those definitely should **not** be static if we want different values for every instance of `Tool_OP`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said the problem is that all the records have the same data (in your comment), the problem is the fact that you are modifying the same instance of an object and then adding another reference to that object in your list.

I recommend some changes to make the code clearer:

```
public static List<Tool_OP> list = new List<Tool_OP>();
BinaryReader fs = new BinaryReader(File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open));
bool isValidReadRecord = true;

while(isValidReadRecord)
{
    Tool_OP item = new Tool_OP();
    isValidReadRecord = item.ReadRecord(fs);

    if(isValidReadRecord)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
};
fs.Close();
```

The key changes here are that we don't have what looks like an open ended loop.  You have a clear condition to end the loop.  And compared to what I saw originally is that the `Tool_OP item` is instantiated new every time.  `Tool_OP item = new Tool_OP();`

If every record has the same data at this point, then you'll need to look at how `Tool_OP` is storing data.  If the information is stored in `static` fields or properties then they will all have whatever the latest data is from `item.ReadRecord()`.

In fact, with your edit, it becomes very clear!  Remove the `static` keyword:

```
class Tool_OP
{
    public string      comment;
    public long        op_idn;
}
```

The `static` keyword means that there is one definition of that field in the entire run time for your class.  They are effectively global values.  Only use `static` if you really intend to share data across all instances of a class.

Comment: fs is not static. It is being passed into a sub-method ReadRecord which is not static. I would use the ref keyword.

Comment: But I do agree that using the keyword static forces the variable to one instance. But, that said, he is passing fs by value and not by reference.

Comment: `Tool_OP.comment` and `Tool_OP.op_idn` were static.  `fs` is a heap object, so passing in that value to the method is just fine.  You would need to use `ref` if `fs` were a struct, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to all...

Now it works without static in the Tool_OP class and the clear code!

Comment: I can delete mine if you prefer.